# How to force login with sfGuard?

Tags: symfony1, sfguard

Does anyone have any of how to force a login action with sfGuard through code? Something like: $this->authenticate('username'); ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was:

```
$user = // sfGuardUser object
$user_id = $user->getId();

$this->getUser()->signIn($user_id, true);
```

... with the second parameter being true/false for "remember me".

See the signIn function in the sfGuardSecurityUser.class.php inside the Plugin lib/user/ to see how it works.

Comment: How do i get an instance of sfGuardUser? I'm trying to do this inside a class that extends sfBasicSecurityUser.

Comment: @carlinhete67: well, in order to log someone in as a sfGuardUser, there must be an sfGuardUser object to log in. That object you can get with a query or sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser() inside a class... but better would be to pass the session user object ($this->getUser()) into your class and then use the getGuardUser() method on that. It would probably be useful if you clarify further what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to log an user directly with a method call, based on it's username. Something like: signIn('username');

And sign it in.

Comment: @Carlinhete67: That's fine, you'll just need to get the id from the username first.

Comment: I don't have the user ID, just it's username. That's why i'm struggling to do this. How can i call the signIn method and force the login with a certain user, without it's id?

Comment: You'll need to get the id from the username to use the signin method: $user = Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardUser')->findOneByUsername($username); $user_id = $user->getId();

Comment: Also, if you're doing this directly from a sfGuard signin form, just pass $values['user'] as the id to the method.

Comment: After getting the id, how do i pass it to sfGuard?

Comment: @Carlinhete67: What do you mean by passing it to sfGuard?

Comment: How do i call sfGuard and make it sign the user with that certain ID i got from a query? I'm manipulating the sfCASUser class.

Comment: Just this: $this->getUser()->signIn($user_id, true);

Comment: I get an error, method from non-object. Probably because i'm calling getUser() on sfCasUser. sfCasUser is extending sfGuardSecurityUser

Comment: I'm also getting Call to a member function getId() on a non-object

Comment: The SIGNIN method always expects and object. I'm sending an ID... how can i turn this ID in a SfGuardUser object? :(

Comment: @Carlinhete67: I'd recommend reading the symfony basics. Check out the "Gentle Introduction to Symfony 1.4". What you've just asked is about as basic as it gets.